# Need to implement view pager with action bar in ginger bread version

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-appcompat

Hi, I am using appcompat library for implement action bar in android lower version (ginger bread), In there i need to implement view pager with action bar but my app was crashing can any one suggest the idea to implement the view pager with action bar in gingerbread version.

Code-

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager pager;
FrameLayout f;
mypageadapter pageradapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//  kkk = getSupportActionBar();
//  kkk.setTitle("jjjj");
    f = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fram);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    List<Fragment> list_fragment = getFragment();
    pageradapter = new mypageadapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            list_fragment);
    pager.setAdapter(pageradapter);

}

private List<Fragment> getFragment() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    List<Fragment> k = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    k.add(fragment1.newInstance("f1"));
    k.add(fragment1.newInstance("f2"));
    k.add(fragment2.newInstance("f3"));
    k.add(fragment1.newInstance("f4"));
    k.add(fragment1.newInstance("f5"));

    return k;
      }
}
```

Xml-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: Post your code and your error message

Comment: @ianhanniballake ya sure

Comment: @ianhanniballake now check this :)

Comment: @mohan check my anser in this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496358/how-to-add-swipe-in-tabs/21596799#21596799

Comment: Its nice. If you need any help on this. tell me.

Comment: sure @KanwaljitSingh which chat room u will be available

Comment: U can send me comment here.